# Implicit function - Finding the $y=f(x)$ for each $x$ base on Newton-Raphson

Tags: numerical-methods

How could I find the $y=f(x)$  for each $x$ in an [implicit function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_differentiation#Implicit_differentiation) base on [Newton-Raphson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) ?

For example  -

Given the implicit function -  $$3x^7+2y^5-x^3+y^3-3=0 $$
how could I find the $f(0)$ base on [Newton-Raphson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) ?

Any idea or hint would be welcome .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, not necessarily $y$ in implicit expression is actually a function of $x$. For instance, implicit equation
$$
x^2+y^2 = 1
$$
doesn't define a function, but two functions (top and bottom semicircles). But, you can say, what points $(x,y)$ satisfy your implicit equation, if $x = 0$.

SO, basically, you have to solve
$$
2y^5+y^3-3=0
$$
From that point, you can apply Newton-Raphson, or any other known solvers, to find those $y$'s.

Answer (score 1):

To find $f(0)$ you are trying to solve $g(y)=2y^5+y^3-3=0$.  Now you can take a derivative to get $g'(y)=10y^4+3y^2$.  You have a function value and its derivative, so you can use Newton-Raphson just fine.  If I start at $y=0.9$ it converges quickly:$$\begin {array}{r r r} y&g(y)&g'(y)\\
0.9&-1.09002&8.991\\
1.021234568&0.286623354&14.00558228\\
1.000769631&0.01001884&13.03544037\\
1.000001047&1.36057E-05&13.00004814\\
1&2.51941E-11&13 \end {array}$$

I only knew to start there because I could see that $y=1$ was a root.  It converges from $0.5$ as well, but takes a bit longer.  In this case this is the only real root in $y$.